# Getting android keystore signature keeps changing after some days

Tags: android, android-keystore, apk-signing

I've created a keystore for my app and has always been signing with it. In the app there's a verification to test if the key hash has changed. However today when I exported the apk with and installed it, the key hash has changed.

Since I've never done anything to the keystore, I suppose I shouldn't change.
Below is the code snippet.

```
fun getSHA(context: Context): String {
        val info: PackageInfo
        var message = ""
        try {
            info = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                if(signature != null){
                    val algo = "SHA256"
                    val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algo)
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                    val encode = Base64.encode(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT)
                    Log.d(TAG, signature.toCharsString())
                    return String(encode).also {
                        MyLog.d(TAG, "\n\n $it")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e1: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            message = "$TAG Exception: " + e1.message
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            message = "$TAG Exception: " + e.message
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            message = "$TAG Exception: " + e.message
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you hash the whole signature. But a signature is not the key only. Also a signature is unique for each signed file, so any time you change a single bit in the APK you will get a new signature. You should better calculate the fingerprint of the signature certificate or the hash of the signature public key (contained in the signature cert) only.

Comment: How a bit can change in Signature when I am using the same keystore always?

Comment: A signature signs data. If you change the data the signature will also change. Otherwise it would be not bound to the data and thus verifying the signature would become impossible (and thus the signature would become useless).

Comment: Then how can I calculate the fingerprint of signature, can share some code snippet?

Comment: Surprisingly I tried to apply your approach and get the SHA256 fingerprint and encode and get the same output as getting from the above shared code output. It means above code is not using the complete signature to encode, it is using only SHA256 fingerprint, but still question is open that why it get changed after a week or some days when keystore is same.